# Django: How to send two pk when Update?

Tags: django

When I update moneylog which relation with moneybook, the error occur :

> NoReverseMatch at /moneylogs/update/8/
>   Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('', 8)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['moneylogs/(?P[0-9]+)/delete/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

I guess this is because there is no moneybook.pk, but I can't find out how to deal with.

could anyone kindly help me please?
**models.py**

```
 class Moneylog(core_models.TimeStampedModel):

        moneybook = models.ForeignKey(
            moneybook_models.Moneybook, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        pay_day = models.DateTimeField(default=NOW)
        payer = models.ForeignKey(
            tempfriend_models.Tempfriend, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="payer")
        dutch_payer = models.ManyToManyField(
            tempfriend_models.Tempfriend, related_name="dutch_payer", blank=True)
        price = models.IntegerField()
        category = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        memo = models.TextField()
```

**views.py**

```
class moneylog_update(UpdateView):
    model = moneylog_models.Moneylog
    form_class = forms.UpdateMoneylogForm
    template_name = "moneylogs/update.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        moneylog = form.save(commit=False)
        moneybook = moneybook_models.Moneybook.objects.get(
            pk=moneylog.moneybook.id)
        moneylog.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return redirect(reverse("moneybooks:detail", kwargs={'pk': moneybook.pk}))
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = "moneylogs"

urlpatterns = [
    path("create/<int:pk>/",
         views.moneylog_create.as_view(), name="create"),
    path("update/<int:pk>/",
         views.moneylog_update.as_view(), name="update"),
    path("<int:moneybook_pk>/delete/<int:moneylog_pk>/",
         views.moneylog_delete, name="delete"),
]
```

**template(moneylog_Form_update.html)**

```
...
        <button class="px-2 py-1 rounded bg-red-500 text-white">{{cta}}</button>
        <a href="{% url 'moneylogs:delete' moneybook.pk moneylog.pk %} " >
            <div class="px-2 py-1 rounded bg-red-500 text-white">삭제하기</div>
        </a>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="{% url 'moneylogs:delete' moneybook.pk moneylog.pk %} " >
```

change to

```
<a href="{% url 'moneylogs:delete' moneylog.moneybook_id moneylog.pk %} " >
```

since you are on moneylog's update page.

However this is not really necessary to pass monebook_id at all because moneylog always has it, so `moneylog` instance is enough to determine which moneybook it is linked to.